# CURL command to JSON with Android Studio

Tags: android, json, curl, httpurlconnection

I want to send following CURL command from my Android App:

```
curl -X POST "http://18.159.200.150:8008/connections/create-invitation?auto_accept=false&multi_use=false&public=false" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ3YWxsZXRfaWQiOiI3Y2MzYWQ3Yi1iY2I1LTQyYzMtYmE5MC0wNzEwOTY2ZmFiNTMifQ.UYJj8w_7792CZStyHmtr0OVT8TXjhgfdsalkj" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}"
```

So I tried to implement it using HttpURLConnection into Android App so I wrote the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        URL_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_url);
        Connect_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);

        Connect_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

         
           String JSONInputString = "{}";

            String result = "";
            try {
                //Connect
                

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://18.159.200.150:8008/connections/create-invitation?auto_accept=false&multi_use=false&public=false")).openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ3YWxsZXRfaWQiOiI3Y2MzYWQ3Yi1iY2I1LTQyYzMtYmE5MC0wNzEwOTY2ZmFiNTMifQ.UYJj8w_7792CZStyHmtr0OVT8TXjhgfdsalkj");
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                byte[] outputBytes = JSONInputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

                outputStream.write(outputBytes);

                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed : HTTP error code : " +
                            + urlConnection.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



                outputStream.close();


                //Read
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                URL_display.setText(result);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

However this code does not work so can someone help me fix it?
There are no errors but I get no response...

Errors that I get:

```
2021-05-04 09:58:28.033 177-177/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=760 uid=10146 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c146,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2021-05-04 09:58:28.097 475-475/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2021-05-04 09:58:28.097 475-475/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-05-04 09:58:28.264 177-177/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=760 uid=10146 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c146,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2021-05-04 09:58:28.506 177-177/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=760 uid=10146 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c146,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2021-05-04 09:58:28.663 481-481/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2021-05-04 09:58:28.664 481-481/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-05-04 09:58:28.735 177-177/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=760 uid=10146 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c146,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

I am pretty new with requests and Android together. I had to setup proxy as well because Agent that I am trying to connect is hosted internally and I have to be connected to the network via VPN. I did that in Gradle properties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn't actually work? Show the stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post that as well. Now it is in the post above. @shmakova

Comment: Is the 'Failed' toast shown?

Comment: He doesn't show Failed toast.. Could you @huytc prove that headers and body are ok?

Comment: I haven't worked with HttpURLConnection before so I can't say for sure but I think it looks OK. Have you tried running the curl command manually? Does it return any data?

Comment: @huytc I tried that and it works perfectly but there is some problem with an app. If you think of something else that could cause a problem, let me know. Thanks for your time! :)